# updating, upgrading debian linux server except a package

Tags: linux, unix, apt, debian-wheezy, update

I was looking for a command line to update/upgrade my VPS with the exception of the web server software. I have Nginx v.1.4.7 on my VPS and don't want it to get updated/upgraded when I run any update/upgrade command line.

I found this question [apt-get update/upgrade list without changing anything](https://serverfault.com/questions/300749/apt-get-update-upgrade-list-without-changing-anything) talking about similar issue except that I want to update everything, but only Nginx.

is it possible to do that? or I have to run an update/upgrade for each single package on my VPS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply have to hold the desired packages, using your prefered package manager, for example:

**Using apt**

to hold:

```
sudo apt-mark hold package_name
```

to remove the holding:

```
sudo apt-mark unhold package_name
```

**Using aptitude**

to hold:

```
sudo aptitude hold package_name
```

to remove the holding:

```
sudo aptitude unhold package_name
```

Comment: thanks@[mvillar](http://serverfault.com/users/220426/mvillar). That was very useful answer.

Answer (score 1):

There is also apt pinning, which is useful for configuration management. Consider this example that pins the version of CFEngine in /etc/apt/preferences.d/cfengine.

```
Package: cfengine-community
Pin-Priority: 1001
Pin: version 3.6.0-1
```

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PinningHowto